# jquery autocomplete input array

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have the following code and what I am trying to do is set up an Autocomplete input box that when it is filled out, create another autocomplete input box underneath it.

- The problem with my code is that
  since I am using blur, it will create
  a new input every time I click off of
  the first one.
- The second problem is
  that I need to setup the autocomplete
  on the newly created input box, but
  if I do it recursively then it will
  crash.

Code:

```
function setupAutoComplete()
{
 var autoCompleteData = $("#listContacts").html().split("<br>");
 //autoCompleteData = replaceAll(autoCompleteData, "&lt;", "<");
 //autoCompleteData = replaceAll(autoCompleteData, "&gt;", ">");
 $("[name|=toemail[]]").autocomplete(autoCompleteData);
 $("[name|=toemail[]]").result(function(event, item) {
    $("[name|=toemail[]]").blur();
 });
 $("[name|=toemail[]]").blur(function(){
  var newString = $(this).val();
  newString = replaceAll(newString, "&lt;", "<");
  newString = replaceAll(newString, "&gt;", ">"); 
  $(this).val(newString);
  var newfield = '<p><label class="" disabled="true"><select name="toSelect[]"><option>To: </option><option>CC: </option><option>BCC: </option></select></label><input type="text" value="" name="toemail[]" /></p>';
  $("#composeTo").append(newfield);
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my own solution.

```
function setupAutoComplete()
{
    var autoCompleteData = $("#listContacts").html().split("<br>");


$("[name|=toemail[]]").each(function(key, value) {
    if (!($(this).hasClass("blurred")))
    {
    $(this).autocomplete(autoCompleteData);
    $(this).result(function(event, item) {
        var newString = $(this).val();
        newString = replaceAll(newString, "&lt;", "<");
        newString = replaceAll(newString, "&gt;", ">"); 
        $(this).val(newString);
        $(this).blur();
    });
    $(this).blur(function(){
        if (!($(this).hasClass("blurred")))
        {
        var newfield = '<p><label class="" disabled="true"><select name="toSelect[]"><option>To: </option><option>CC: </option><option>BCC: </option></select></label><input type="text" value="" name="toemail[]" /></p>';
        $("#composeTo").append(newfield);
        setupAutoComplete();
        $(this).addClass("blurred");
        }
    });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than setting up the auto complete on the elements as a group you should be doing it individually as each one is created. This will stop the recursion.

Secondly to avoid the onblur event firing when you click somewhere else on the screen you should catch the tab key being pressed on a keypress.